# Selenium Python: error 'str' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to perform a right click on an element using action chains. I have a locators.py file with locators grouped in classes.
When I call ActionChains and context_click in a function that performs actions on a page, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\***\Tests\test_ZRLPCHS.py", line 23, in test_ZRLP
    fill_zrlp(self)
  File "C:\***\Source\Functions.py", line 1096, in fill_zrlp
    upload_dossier(self)
  File "C:\***\Source\Functions.py", line 968, in upload_dossier
    section = driver.find_element(*nat_dossier.txt_other_section)
  File "C:\***\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1244, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

The code I'm trying to execute:

```
section = driver.find_element(*nat_dossier.txt_other_section)
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.context_click(section)
action.perform()
```

The locator itself looks like this:

```
class DossierStmnt2(object):
    txt_other_section = (By.ID, "j1_66_anchor")
```

I've tried passing the locator as a tuple, without referring to the locators.py, but that didn't help.

Update:
driver is defined like this:
driver = webdriver.Chrome

I've just solved the problem by rewriting the code to this:

```
def upload_dossier(self):
  print("Uploading dossier")
  self.driver.find_element(*nat_app.btn_dossier).click()
  section = self.driver.find_element(*nat_dossier.txt_other_section)
  action = ActionChains(self.driver)
  action.context_click(section)
  action.perform()
```

Looks like the problem was in the **self**.driver in ActionChains.

Comment: Post relevant code

Comment: Update the question with relevant code.

Comment: How is `driver` defined? This only makes sense if `driver` refers to a `class` and not an instance of a `class`.

Comment: I'm guessing somewhere in your code you have `self.driver = driver()` and maybe some arguments supplied to `driver`. The reason you were receiving the error was `driver.find_element(*nat_dossier.txt_other_section)` is basically using `webdriver.Chrome.find_element(*nat_dossier.txt_other_section)`. That doesn't work because `find_element` is an instance method expected to be called on an instance, not the class itself. When called on the class, the first argument gets assigned to `self` leading to the error you received.